# The type initializer for 'Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection' threw an exception. SSIS - Sybase

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, connection, sybase

im trying to create a batch job with Visual Studio Integration services 32 bits that allow connect a Sybase Database, i have been intalled the skd 16.0.030.040 from SAP, everyting is ok because i tested the connection with a client, but when i tested the connection in the Visual Studio appears the next error "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. The type initializer for 'Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection' threw an exception.".

I have been try change the version for the Sybase.Data.AseClient from 32bits to 64bits but it does not work.

The steps to can solve the error